# How to fix false Error 6036 raised by Entity Framework in Visual Studio Error List Window

Tags: entity-framework-4, edmx

I changed my edmx file so that all EF classes are internal. Inside the classes all properties are marked as public. The project compiles, but I get false error messages in the Error List Window in Visual Studio.

```
Error 6036: EntityType 'A' has 'internal' accessibility and EntitySet 'B' has a get property with 'public' accessibility. The get property of the EntitySet must not have less restrictive access than the containing EntityType has.
```

Basically I have this situation

```
        internal class A
        {
        }

        internal class B
        {
            public A A
            {
                get { return new A(); }
            }
        }
```

this code compiles without any problem.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555072/changing-entity-accessibility?

Comment: thanks for the link. looks like same problem. i am not working on this issue anymore though.